# Database Modeling Computers and Software Installed on Computers - What Structure Do I Use?

Tags: sql, database

I am structuring a database for software installed on computers. Software can be installed on multiple computers, and computers can of course have multiple software installed on them.

All that is stored for the software is the name and version.

So, as of now I have thought of creating a table for every software. The table would have a column representing the ID of the corresponding computer, as well as the version of the software installed on that computer.

As far as the computers go, I just have one table that holds all the info for each computer.

Is this the best way to structure this database?

Comment: the question you want to ask is what information do I need to get from the database. Then look at what data you need to store for you to be able to get that information. Once you have that you can look at the type of schema you want, relational or Star? and then how normalized you want your data etc...

Comment: Please edit your title to be specific about your issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the best way to structure this database?

I will never understand where people get the idea to create a *separate table* for every record in their database.  But boy does this idea come up a lot :)

You have two "things":

- Software
- Computer

So you have two entity tables:

```
Software
----------
ID
Name
Version

Computer
----------
ID
[other data?]
```

And since it's a many-to-many relationship, you have a connecting table to represent the relationship:

```
ComputerSoftware
----------
ComputerID
SoftwareID
```

The primary key on the connecting table can be a composite of those two values, or you can have a separate `ID` for consistency with the other tables.  Sometimes that depends heavily on the data access framework you're using.

The point is, you shouldn't modify your *schema* based on adding/removing *records*.  Structure the schema to represent the data then just add/modify/remove *records* in that schema.

Comment: Hmm, so say  I want to find all the software installed on a particular computer system. Then I am going to search the 'ComputerSoftware' table for all entries corresponding to the computer system, and then I can get the software information by querying the software table with the respective SoftwareID.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what other uniquely identifying features you're putting on your software table. The way you have it set up now, it might be a bit harder to create queries for specific software, since you'll have a lot of duplicates. Also, it seems like there are different versions of software on different computers. Here is a structure I would suggest:

```
software
    id
    ...
computers
    id
    ...
computers_software
    software_id
    computer_id
    software_version
    ...
```